# MessageBox Threading Issues

Tags: c++, multithreading, variables, visual-c++, messagebox

I have a strange behaviour of the Messagebox started in a Thread using this code:

```
DWORD WINAPI CreateMessageBox(LPVOID lpParam) {
    MessageBoxA(NULL, (char*)lpParam, "", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
std::string msg = "Hello World";
CreateThread(NULL, 0, &CreateMessageBox, msg.c_str(), 0, NULL);
```

While this code works normally:

```
DWORD WINAPI CreateMessageBox(LPVOID lpParam) {
    MessageBoxA(NULL, (char*)lpParam, "", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
CreateThread(NULL, 0, &CreateMessageBox, "Hello World", 0, NULL);
```

I can't understand why it's working when it's not a variable, and if I change it to a variable, an Empty MessageBox is Displayed, but I Expected an "Hello World!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg` is a local variable (allocated on stack) and it will be destroyed as soon as the function/method containing that code returns. So, the thread will be accessing invalid memory while using the `lparam`.

Some of the solutions could be:

```
1.) declare 'msg' as static - probably not a good idea
2.) allocate 'msg' on heap, but then you will have to destroy it somewhere
3.) make 'msg' a member variable
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? I don't understand what you exactly mean. If I declare msg as static (was the easiest I think), I get an Segmentation fault, so I changed it back, because you wrote not a good idea. Can you provide me an example what you mean with the other 2 things?

Comment: You shouldn't get an access violation if you use static variable. Anyway, regarding 3rd option, you have this code in some class, right? I mean you tagged your question with a 'c++' tag. Then add `std::string msg` as a member variable to that class.